# nifi + executescript count lines in file using python

Tags: python, apache-nifi

Hi i need to get the numbers of line in a csv file exclusive the first line which are headers
I need to store the number of lines in a attribute and parse the flowfile untouched to the next processor

I was thinking of using extracttext but i don't think that a regular expression can do this.

So next step would be a executeScript processor. 
I was think of a python script with following template

```
flowFile = session.get() 
if (flowFile != None):
# All processing code starts at this indent
attrMap = ['numberOflines': '1', 'myAttr2': Integer.toString(2)]
flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
#Do something to get numbers of lines in the flow file
i =0;
    for line in flowfile
        i+=1

flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'attribute_numberOfLines', i)
if errorOccurred:
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
else:
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

## implicit return at the end

This will not run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a [SplitText](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitText/index.html) processor with the Line Split Count set to some number higher than the largest number of possible lines in your files (such as 1 million). You can also set the Header Line Count to 1 if you want the total number of lines minus the header. You'll get the same flow file(s) out, but with an attribute text.line.count that will contain the number of lines.

Comment: Thanks, haven't though of that approach but it worked fine.